# changing keys in a solo

Tags: scales, key-signatures

Let's say I'm playing in C and the progression is I ii V iii IV V I.
When the IV (Fmaj) is playing, what are your thoughts on what notes I can use.

I can obviously use anything in C which will sound natural in the mood of the song. However can I just ignore that and use the F major scale. 
Since there is only one note different between the scales it should always sound natural right?

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/47745/lead-guitar-stay-in-single-key may be of interest.

Comment: It wouldn't sound natural, but it would give you a pretty satisfying result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the difference between being *IN* a key and *ON* a particular chord. Here, you're *IN* C, but *ON* F. All the C major notes will work, although as you're probably aware, some work better than others, and it depends where in the bar and also what order and length each is played.And also which chors precede and follow that bar. In your example, it's G, which feels like it'll lead back to I (C), which it does. So the melody, of any quality, doesn't want to hint at modulating to IV, 'cos that's not where the song is heading.

The only difference in the F notes is the Bb as opposed to the B natural. That is a pivotal note, belonging often in a C7 chord. Which, I'm sure you're aware, is the one used to lead on to F, funnily enough.So, by incorporating the Bb in a solo, you're inferring a change TO F, but you're already on it. At the end of the day, it's really down to the soloist, and the other notes, as I said earlier, but I think B is a better fit more times than Bb. You could also say that on a V chord (G), you should/could/would use F#, as that's the differring note from G.

Listen to 'Moon River', bar 3. Hank puts an F chord and writes a B natural over it, at the important beginning of that bar. Not a Bb.

Comment: Tim I really like this answer, thank you for your time and considered answer, it's charitable for us who are still trying to grasp simple concepts